# Get Google Analytics to show seamless search console data from HTTP property to HTTPS property after migration

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, https, migration

**Background:**

Google Search Console (GSC) can provide up to 16 months of search performance data, and this can be reported in Google Analytics (GA) when GSC and GA are associated (GA > Acquisition > Search console > Landing Pages/Countries/Devices/Queries).

Advice I've read suggests that, upon migrating to HTTPS, four properties should be created in GSC:

- `http:// example.com`
- `http:// www.example.com`
- `https:// example.com`
- `https:// www.example.com`

**Issue:**

When a site is migrated from HTTP to HTTPS, and the association in GA is updated (GA > Admin > Property Settings > Adjust Search Console), it appears that that 16 months is interupted and historical reporting no longer available.

I migrated a site to HTTPS 6 months ago. Having verified the four versions in search console I changed the association in GA to the appropriate HTTPS version. Now, in GA, my GSC report only reports back to that point in time.

I can only see a way to 'Adjust Search Console' in GA to point to one GSC property. But is there a way to retain a seamless 16 months report when migrating HTTP to HTTPS?